# I am throwing exception in Cakephp 2.5 from a condition, using PHP 7.2, it throwing nothing, why?

Tags: exception, php-7.2, cakephp-2.5

I have updated the php version in my cakephp 2.5 application, here what i see the exception is not working in my application.

haven't get any solution yet to try anything

> > > if (count($suborgs)== 0) {
> > >           throw new InternalErrorException("User ".$user['id']." does not have suborgs and only have PRINCIPAL scope");
> > >       }

Exception should work for me

Comment: What version of PHP were you using before?

Comment: @GregSchmidt  First of all thanks for your response, I were using php 5.6 before.